# Webpack appears to be attempting to bundle /usr/bin

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, webpack

I think this has to do with Webpack trying to pack the system files within ".bin" in node_modules??

I repeatedly got the error that JS was running out of heap space, regardless of whether or not I increased the node size limit to 7GB, then tried running npm run build --verbose:

[image]

```
(base) Nicholass-MBP:tester nicholas$ npm run build --verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   '/Users/nicholas/.nvm/versions/node/v14.13.0/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/Users/nicholas/.nvm/versions/node/v14.13.0/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'run',
npm verb cli   'build',
npm verb cli   '--verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@6.14.8
npm info using node@v14.13.0
npm verb run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
npm info lifecycle @reach-sh/tester@~prebuild: @reach-sh/tester@
npm info lifecycle @reach-sh/tester@~build: @reach-sh/tester@

> @reach-sh/tester@ build /Users/nicholas/Desktop/Web/Reach/tester
> webpack --display-modules && cp src/index.html dist/indexx.html

^Cnpm verb lifecycle @reach-sh/tester@~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
npm verb lifecycle @reach-sh/tester@~build: PATH: /Users/nicholas/.nvm/versions/node/v14.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/nicholas/Desktop/Web/Reach/tester/node_modules/.bin:/Users/nicholas/.nvm/versions/node/v14.13.0/bin:/Users/nicholas/anaconda2/bin:/Users/nicholas/anaconda2/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
npm verb lifecycle @reach-sh/tester@~build: CWD: /Users/nicholas/Desktop/Web/Reach/tester
npm info lifecycle @reach-sh/tester@~postbuild: @reach-sh/tester@
```

```
const path = require('path');
var htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
//var nodeExternals = require('web')

const clientConfig = {
    target: 'web',
    entry: './src/simple.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'client.bundle.js'
    },
    externals: [
        {sysfiles: '.bin'}
    ],
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'), path.resolve(__dirname, 'stdlib'), 'node_modules'],
        //extensions: ['*', '.js'],
      alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js', // 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' for webpack 1
        'ethers$': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@reach-sh/stdlib/node_modules/ethers/dist/ethers.min.js')
      }
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
      {
        test: /\.mjs$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        type: "javascript/auto"
      }
      ]
    },
  plugins: [new htmlWebpackPlugin()]
};

module.exports = clientConfig;
```

Comment: I created the stdlib folder using sudo cp and so I think the permissions for the folder are too high (trailing + in folder permissions), thus revealing the system file .bin to webpack. Was able to resolve the issue by recreating the folder.